# Can't find a way to add texture to all faces on object

Tags: modeling, texturing

Newbie question but I cant seem to figure out how to get the text to show up on all faces in the UV Editor.

I add the texture and drag it around in the UV editor to get the texture in the right position. But can't find a way to get the texture to appear on the bottom half of the object.

The object was originally two default cubes shaped and then joined together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd> if that means anything.

[image]

Comment: It seems you did not UV Unwrap the object, you can select all the object in edit mode faces mode, then press U > Light Map Pack.

You can learn more about UV Mapping here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujlCH15v8gw

Comment: hello maybe pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I have been developing a map for a mini project. I have imported many other models into blender. Is there any way to individually send a few files or the files that you want?

Comment: Unwrapping the Uv somewhat worked. It spread the texture over a few more of the faces but there is still two faces that the material isn't present on. I really have no idea. I watched the video that was linked but they didn't run into this problem as they were using the default cube. The shape I am using doesn't have an symetrical transform and that is my own guess as to why the texture is showing on it properly.

Answer (score 2):

As Yogi mentioned in the comments you haven`t unwrapped your mesh correctly. Just tab into edit mode, select all your faces by pressing 'A', press'U', select the 'cube projection' option and then scale your UV unwrap. I have roughly recreated your object and shown you the steps in the GIF given below.

If this solution doesn`t completely work then in object mode select your mesh, press Ctrl+A, select the 'Rotation and scale' option to reset the scale and rotational value you had set to the default '0'(so unwrapping will be done correctly). Then tab into edit mode, press 'A', press 'Shift+N' to recalculate normals.

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, Kinda. I decided to remodel the steps by instead extruding the faces and making them out of one cube rather than combining 2 cubes together. I then applied all the steps from the gif and It worked. Thanks So Much!

Comment: no problem happy to help. I had no idea that you had two cubes I thought it was just one cube extruded.